Is there a way to refactor this code? Can I create an helper from it?
I need all the below code to be able to persist in the URL (query string) some variables I'm using in a Svelte 5 / Svelte Kit project page.
I also need to assign URL query params to variables on page reload or page change.
As you can see, the code is very repetitive, and I think there must be a better way (better = DRY and faster).
I created a small reproduction.
What do you think?
// condition, pagination and searchText comes from $props()

let firstLoad = $state(true);

$effect(() => {
    if (firstLoad) return;

    const url = new URL(window.location.toString());

    const paramCondition = url.searchParams.get('condition');
    const paramPagination = url.searchParams.get('pagination');
    const paramSearchText = url.searchParams.get('searchText');

    const actualCondition = isAnEmptyOrFalsyObject(condition) ? null : JSON.stringify(condition);
    const actualPagination = isAnEmptyOrFalsyObject(pagination) ? null : JSON.stringify(pagination);
    const actualSearchText = !searchText ? null : searchText;

    let shouldGo = false;

    if (paramCondition !== actualCondition) {
        if (actualCondition) {
            url.searchParams.set('condition', actualCondition);
        } else {
            url.searchParams.delete('condition');
        }

        shouldGo = true;
    }

    if (paramPagination !== actualPagination) {
        if (actualPagination) {
            url.searchParams.set('pagination', actualPagination);
        } else {
            url.searchParams.delete('pagination');
        }

        shouldGo = true;
    }

    if (paramSearchText !== actualSearchText) {
        if (actualSearchText) {
            url.searchParams.set('searchText', actualSearchText);
        } else {
            url.searchParams.delete('searchText');
        }

        shouldGo = true;
    }

    if (shouldGo) goto(url, { replaceState: false, keepFocus: true, noScroll: true });
});

afterNavigate(({ to }) => {
    if (!to) return;

    const paramCondition = to.url.searchParams.get('condition');
    const paramPagination = to.url.searchParams.get('pagination');
    const paramSearchText = to.url.searchParams.get('searchText');

    if (paramCondition && paramCondition !== JSON.stringify(condition)) {
        condition = JSON.parse(paramCondition);
    }

    if (paramPagination && paramPagination !== JSON.stringify(pagination)) {
        pagination = JSON.parse(paramPagination);
    }

    if (paramSearchText && paramSearchText !== searchText) {
        searchText = paramSearchText;
    }

    if (firstLoad) firstLoad = false;
});


State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.

extract helper
For each of condition, pagination, and search text
you apply the identical logic.
So create a boolean helper that implements the desired side effects.
And keep ORing its result into your flag.
(I probably would have named it want_redirect, but whatever.)
extra test
Three times you do this sort of thing:
    if (paramCondition && paramCondition !== JSON.stringify(condition)) {
        condition = JSON.parse(paramCondition);
    }

That second conjunct looks like a premature optimization.
Does .parse() really cost so much that we're willing
to clutter the code with an extra .stringify() to avoid it?
I say that once we know we have a condition parameter,
just unconditionally parse and assign it, to make the code more concise.

Thank you very much. The second part is brilliant. Thanks! I'm a bit in doubt about the first (extract helper). Can you write a small example of what you mean?
